# How to run Dart code from Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, dart

I'm building an `asp.net` website using Visual Studio 2012. I'm considering adding some `dart` code into it.

I'm trying to check how this thing works: I downloaded the [DartVS](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69112f14-62d0-40fb-9ccc-03e3534e7121) visual studio extension, and I took a [ready dart code](https://www.dartlang.org/codelabs/darrrt/) from the web. The dart code runs fine on `dartium` when I run it from the `dart IDE`.

I copied and pasted the code to Visual Studio (that now recognizes dart thanks to the extension). When I run it from there - I could see that the GUI appears, but the buttons don't seem to work. I put a breakpoint in the dart code's `main` function but it doesn't seem to get there.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

> **Edit:** Although not full Visual Studio, I have created a VS Code extension that does support debugging [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.dart-code).

I'm the author of the extension you linked. Currently, there is no debug support. If you're going to launch from VS in the browser, you'll need to add Dartium to the list of browsers in Visual Studio.

The current version of the extension is very limited and just uses regular expressions to syntax highlight and runs the command-line Analyzer for error info. Both of these kinda work; but have some flaws.

[I'm working on a new version](https://github.com/DartVS/DartVS); which is backed by a service written by Google, which has very reliable syntax highlighting, tooltips, GotoDefinition, code-completion and more. It's not ready for testing quite yet; but it'll be pushed as an update to the extension you already have once it's done.

The plan is to ultimately include Visual-Studio debugging; but for now, I'd recommend using Dartium and debugging in the developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the code from VS - where does it get executed? Dart is only supported in Dartium so far - so if you want it to work in any browser, you have to use dart2js for now.

I don't know what that Extension does but this might be the problem.

Regards, Robert

Comment: Thanks, I tried running it with Chromium as well... still no difference (it's the chromium that comes with the dart IDE, so I think it's OK in that aspect).

Answer (score 1):

You can start `pub serve` and Dartium manually and point Dartium to the URL `pub serve` listens to.
DartEditor also launches `pub serve` for this.

I don't know if your extension has any debugging support but in Dartium you can debug Dart and JavaScript code like JavaScript code in the normal Chrome browser dev-tools.

Comment: When you say start pub serve ... do you mean simply run Dartium and then point it to the URL where the Dart code is situated?

Comment: `pub` is a multipurpose tool for Dart. It manages dependencies, invokes Dart-to-JavaScript compilation, ...
`pub serve` is a command to be executed from the command line and launches a web server that serves the files from the source directory. When a browser requests JavaScript (Chrome, Firefox, ....) `pub serve` compiles Dart to JavaScript on the fly and serves the compiled JavaScript instead of Dart code.
`pub serve` is also invoked by DartEditor and other IDEs with Dart support.